# HTTP observable returns undefined/null

Tags: http, angular, ionic2, observable

i have created providers page and i am having my post and get request in it

here is my services which returns observable

```
post(url: string,data:any): Observable<any>{

   return this.http.post(this.configurator.restServerBaseUrl+url,data)
    .map((result:Response)=> {
      result.json()
    })
  }
```

here is my component code

```
 submit(){
    this.rest.post('/validateUser',validateUserObj)
    .subscribe((result)=>{
      this.logger.debug("checking data of success " +JSON.stringify(result));

    });
  }
}
```

here my result is giving me **undefined**

> in my services if i map like this it works fine `.map((result:Response)=>result.json())`

if i apply bracket i am getting undefined.

> can some one help me in understand the observable i have checked in angula.io but i am feeling difficult to understand there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short form returns the result of `expression` implicitly

```
(param) => expression;
```

The long form with brackets supports multiple statements but you have to explicitly `return`

```
(param) => { 
  let x = this.doSomething();
  return x; 
}
```

Comment: you can see here `post(url: string,data:any): Observable<any>` i am trying to return observable if i try to return x as you said then that means i am not returning any observable. so as per your answer what it is returning any help

Comment: That was just a generic example. In your case just add `return` before `result.json()`